# Date format error in java

Tags: java, jsp

When I used date format in jsp page in tomcat 6 or 7 which is running with jre 7 it doesn't shown any error.

But when I uploaded my code in to the other machine which is running with jre 6 or 5 it's showing bellow error.
In my code I imported java.util.java.text package also.

```
     org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page       /entsug.jsp at line 24

      21: String imag =(String)session.getAttribute("image");
      22: String frrr =(String)session.getAttribute("frrr");
      23: String moto = request.getParameter("sugge");
      24: java.text.DateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY   HH:mm"); 
      25: String da=df.format(new java.util.Date()); 
      26: 
      27:
```

Stacktrace:

```
       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException
       (JspServletWrapper.java:510)
   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

root cause

```
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'Y'
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(Unknown Source)
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(Unknown Source)
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(Unknown Source)
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jsp.entsug_jsp._jspService(entsug_jsp.java:88)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Comment: Its problem in jre version. you use proper jre version.

Comment: i think all answers are right..might as well give a vote up for every1..

Comment: @User211  vote up requires 15 reputation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

comparing the API Docs for Java 6 and Java 7 holds the answer:

[SimpleDateFormat SE 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) only allows lower case 'y' to display the year.
[SimpleDateFormat SE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) additionally allows capital case 'Y' to display what is called "Week year"

Good luck!

Comment: (And you definitely don't want week-year here...)

Answer (score 0):

Try small 'y' instead of capital think that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
java.text.DateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy  HH:mm");
```

Lower case y